# client-side-validations custom method undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, client-side-validation

loading a form with a custom validator is generating a NoMethodError

```
undefined method `validates_soggetti'
```

set-up

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'client_side_validations', :github => 'bcardarella/client_side_validations', :branch => '3-2-stable'
```

Initializer has block for attached message uncommented.
app/validators/soggetti_validator.rb contains

```
class SoggettiValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator

  def validate(record)
    unless :quantita >= :soggetti
      record.errors.add(:soggetti, :too_big) 
    end
  end

  module ActiveModel::Validations::HelperMethods
    def validates_soggetti(*attr_names)
      validates_with SoggettiValidator, _merge_attributes(attr_names)
    end
  end

 end
```

Model

```
class Bozza < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :height, :quantita, :soggetti, :width

  validates_presence_of :height, :width, :quantita
  validates_numericality_of :height, :width
  validates_numericality_of :quantita, :only_integer => true
  validates_numericality_of :soggetti, :only_integer => true

  validates_soggetti :soggetti
end
```

Edited error message for YAML tables and a rails.validations.customValidators.js file
Also tried by adding, in application.js

```
//= require rails.validations.customValidators
```

Only the custom validation will not kick in.  I am assuming the issue is with the module definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by creating under /lib a validations_helpers.rb file with the module statement.

```
  module ActiveModel::Validations::HelperMethods
    def validates_soggetti(*attr_names)
      validates_with SoggettiValidator, _merge_attributes(attr_names)
    end
  end
```

and calling the module in relevant controllers.

also the model needs to specify the rails3 way:

```
  validates :height, :presence => true, :numericality => true
  validates :width, :presence => true, :numericality => true
  validates :quantita, :presence => true, :numericality => {:only_integer => true}
  validates :soggetti, :soggetti => true, :numericality => {:only_integer => true}
```

which is slightly different from the instructions on https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations
which suggests validates_myCustomValidation